# Is there any way to add a list of keywords to a Google site?

Tags: seo, google-search, google-sites, keyword-search

My question is about is there any way to add keywords in the metadata of a Google site

(like `<meta name="keywords" content=" keyword1 , keyword2 "/>` )

Currently we are adding **Alt text** to every image in the site, with the keywords associated to each one.

Our objective is to manage one single list of keywords per all the G-Site, and get the best possible position in a Google search, based on these keywords.

Comment: Google has [not used meta keywords since 2009](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html) and its algorithm is smart enough to ignore a simple space separated list of keywords. There is no substitute for proper content.

Answer (score 2):

If you are aiming for SEO you may try adding your keyword into your site title, slug, and meta as well, [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-edit-the-meta-title-in-WordPress-without-a-plugin) is some link for you.
[This](https://yoast.com/meta-descriptions/) is what you should notice.

Well if you website happened to be built by *WordPress*, I will recommend you to install SEO plugins like **Yoast** or **AllinOneSEO**.

Try Yoast guide [here](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/titles-and-meta-descriptions/).

You may try dig out more Yoast blog as I found that it was quite detailed (for your focused keyword usage part) try this [link](https://yoast.com/focus-keyword/) and go for more.